# Calculate transformation parameters from known common points

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, arcmap, parameters, translation

I have 9 points both in a known and unknown coordinate system. Is there a way to calculate the transformation parameters with QGIS or ArcMap? Or any other free software?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Try ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html with `-gcp` option

> -gcp <ungeoref_x> <ungeoref_y> <georef_x> <georef_y>
>
> Add the indicated ground control point. This option may be provided
> multiple times to provide a set of GCPs.